# is it raid configure or not

Tags: raid, hard-drive

Please tell me about configuring RAID-0.

I have two hard disks, one is 146 GB

I configure raid successfully, but when I look at Disk Managerment there is only DISK 0

```
Drive C 50 GB (48.8) GB
Drive E 50 GB (48.8) GB
Drive F 50 GB (175) GB
```

Where is disk 1?

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather from your post it seems you are trying to use two different size disks in a raid 0. The raid array will only use the size of the smallest disk so if you have a 50GB disk and a 75GB disk they would be treated as two 50GB disks and appear as 100GB to the OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two hard disks that are striped in a RAID 0, your OS will only see one hard drive.  It sounds like you just have a few partitions on your RAID 0 (although it's hard to tell from the grammar).